# Extract DataRow with specific column from a DataSet view in C#

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, datarow

I am want to get a specific row from a dataset, not the entire row but only specifics column from the row
it's should be something like that:

```
 dataRow datarow1 = myDataSet.Tables["table1"].Column["column3 
            and column4"].Select(column1='1' and column2='specificvalue');
```

someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess:

```
var datarows = myDataSet.Tables["table1"].AsEnumerable()
        .Where(x=> x.Field<int>("col1") == 1 && x.Field<string>("col2") == "specificvalue")
        .Select(x=>new 
          {
             col3 = x.Field<int>("col3"),
             col4 = x.Field<int>("col4")
          })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different syntax:

```
var result =  from row in set.Tables["table1"].AsEnumerable()
              where  row.Field<int>("column1") == 1 &&
                     row.Field<string>("column2") == "specificValue"
              select new { Column3 = row.Field<string>("Column3"), 
                           Column4 = row.Field<string>("Column4") };
```